# How can i find out size of RethinkDB table?

Tags: rethinkdb

I can't figure out how to get the data size of 'test.events' table.

```
r.db('rethinkdb').table('stats').whatGoesHere()
// Output size of 'events' table
```

Related: [Get size of Rethinkdb database with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907568/get-size-of-rethinkdb-database-with-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will list space allocated on HDD across all nodes in RethinkDB cluster:

```
r.db("rethinkdb")
  .table("stats")
  .filter({db:'test', table:'events'})
  .map(doc => doc('storage_engine')('disk')('space_usage')('data_bytes').default(0))
  .sum()
```

Alternatively, to list table sizes in MB:

```
r.db("rethinkdb").table("stats")
  .hasFields('db', 'table')
  .group('db', 'table')
  .map(doc => doc('storage_engine')('disk')('space_usage')('data_bytes').default(0))
  .sum()
  .ungroup()
  .map(doc => ({db: doc('group').nth(0), table: doc('group').nth(1), size: doc('reduction').div(1024).div(1024)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.count()` to do that.

Comment: I believe @AJcodez means the size of the table on disk.

Comment: mlucy thanks, but yeah dalanmiller is right hoping for size on disk to estimate cost

Comment: Ah, sorry!  You can get that information from the stats system table: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/system-stats/

Answer (score 0):

To list table sizes in MB:

```
r.db('rethinkdb').table('stats')
  .hasFields('db', 'table')
  .group('db', 'table')
  .map(doc => doc('storage_engine')('disk')('space_usage')('data_bytes').default(0))
  .sum()
  .ungroup()
  .map(doc => ({db: doc('group').nth(0), table: doc('group').nth(1), size: doc('reduction').div(1024).div(1024).round().coerceTo('string').add('MB')}))
```

To show the total of all tables in GB:

```
r.db('rethinkdb').table('stats')
  .hasFields('db', 'table')
  .group('db', 'table')
  .map(doc => doc('storage_engine')('disk')('space_usage')('data_bytes').default(0))
  .sum()
  .ungroup()
  .map(doc => ({db: doc('group').nth(0), table: doc('group').nth(1), size: doc('reduction').div(1024).div(1024)}))
  .sum('size')
  .div(1024)
  .round()
  .coerceTo('string')
  .add('GB')
```